# Conditional operator and Comparison Delegate

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

Given two implementations of Comparison methods:

```
// compares by Key...
private static int CompareByKey(KeyValuePair<int, string> x, KeyValuePair<int, string> y)

{
    return x.Key.CompareTo(y.Key);
}

// compares by Value...
private static int CompareByValue(KeyValuePair<int, string> x, KeyValuePair<int, string> y)
{
    return x.Value.CompareTo(y.Value);
}
```

Why wouldn't the following conditional operator code block compile:

```
Comparison<KeyValuePair<int, string>> sortMethod;
sortMethod = isSortByActualValue ? CompareByKey : CompareByValue;
```

Compiler error: "Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'method group' and 'method group'"

However, the equivalent code block using if-else does not have any issue:

```
Comparison<KeyValuePair<int, string>> sortMethod;
if (isSortByActualValue)
    sortMethod = CompareByKey;
else
    sortMethod = CompareByValue;
```

(all good in both assignments above)

So does the conditional operator, if I cast the Comparison delegate:

```
Comparison<KeyValuePair<int, string>> sortMethod;
sortMethod = isSortByActualValue ? (Comparison<KeyValuePair<int, string>>) CompareByKey : CompareByValue;
```

(all good in the assignment above, when cast even though casting was only on the true part)

Comment: How are CompareByAcutalValue and CompareByDisplayValue defined?  You only show the definition for CompareByKey and CompareByValue.

Comment: The code snippet in my posting was edited for clarity. I didn't realize that I changed the name (of methods) only partially. Thanks Eric, I have updated the all references to CompareByActualValue to CompareByKey (and CompareByDisplayValue to CompareByValue).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Th error method actually says it all but it’s not quite intuitive. If you use a method name without invoking the method, you are handling a *method group*. “group”, because a method could be overloaded and the name can indicate any of the overloaded methods.

Now, method groups are convertible implicitly to a delegate with matching signature, this is why your assignment in `if` works.

So far, so good. However, the conditional operator `?:` needs to deduce a common type to which its second and third arguments can be implicitly converted, and it does not consider all conversions for that (this would have diverse problems). It merely looks whether both arguments have the same type, or whether one is implicitly convertible into the other.

This is not the case here: although both arguments are method groups, they are in fact *different* method groups with distinct types, and you cannot convert one method group into another. Even though both can readily be converted into a delegate, the compiler forbids this usage.

The same is true for other types, by the way:

```
object = someBool ? "" : New List<Integer>();
```

also fails to compile, for the same reason. And again, we can make this compile by explicitly casting either of the arguments to a common base type:

```
object = someBool ? (object) "" : New List<Integer>();
```

Comment: So why doesn't `isSortByActualValue ? CompareByKey : CompareByKey` compile? Aren't they the same method group?

Comment: @svick There doesn’t exist a conversion from method group to method group, regardless of the method group. I should have made that clearer, and it’s a rather particular case since no ordinary type lacks this conversion. I don’t know how this is precisely stated in the C# specification.

Comment: +1, thank you for explaining with another example containing the conditional operator. It makes a lot of sense to feel compiler's confusion to deduce the correct type especially when the second and third arguments can fall into different (but related) types.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an expression like your `CompareByKey`, it doesn't have any specific .Net type, but has a special type “method group”. That's because you could have several methods called `CompareByKey` and it's unclear which one do you want (and it works exactly the same even if you have only one method). Also, it's unclear what delegate type do you want, e.g. `Comparison<KeyValuePair<int, string>>` or `Func<KeyValuePair<int, string>, int>`.

What can you do with method groups? You can use them to explicitly create a delegate (`new Comparison<KeyValuePair<int, string>>(CompareByKey)`) and they are also implicitly convertible to delegates. This is why your `if` version works.

So, what does that have to do with your problem? When you have a conditional operator, the compiler has to figure out the type of the whole expression and it can't use the type of the variable you assign it to (that's not how type inference works in C#). And since both of the expressions are method groups and method groups are treated as different types with no implicit conversions between each other, the type of the whole expression cannot be determined. Which is why you get the error.

You already found a fix: either don't use conditional operator or specify the type of one of the operands explicitly by using a cast (or delegate constructor).